# AEM customization function in javascript

Tags: javascript, aem-6

I am very new in AEM. I have got one task of field customization. But I have issue to write code in Javascript. I want to right code in javascript for some reason.

Here is code that I want to convert in Javascript.

```js
$(document).on("foundation-contentloaded", function(e) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in javascript instead of above code.

```js
var myvar = '$(document).on("foundation-contentloaded", function(e) {});
```